# Error using roll_lm in a debian machine

Tags: r, linux, debian

The following piece of simple code works perfectly on my local windows machine

```
require(roll)
x = matrix(rnorm(100),100,1)
y = matrix(rnorm(100),100,1)
roll_lm(x,y,10)
```

However, on a debian distant machine, it crashes with this error message:

```
caught illegal operation
address 0x7f867a59ee04, 
cause 'illegal operand'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("roll_roll_lm", PACKAGE = "roll", x, y, as.integer(width),     as.numeric(weights), as.logical(center_x), as.logical(center_y),     as.logical(scale_x), as.logical(scale_y), as.integer(min_obs),     as.logical(complete_obs), as.logical(na_restore), as.character(match.arg(parallel_for)))
2: roll_lm(x, y, 10)

Possible actions:  
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled) 
2: normal R exit 
3: exit R without saving workspace 
4: exit R saving workspace*
```

Option 1 : abort (with core dump, if enabled)  gives:

Illegal instruction

I am clueless on how to interpret this message.
Any help? Thanks.

Some info :

**R.version**               _
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          3
minor          2.5
year           2016
month          04
day            14
svn rev        70478
language       R
version.string R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
nickname       Very, Very Secure Dishes

**The system:**
Linux machineName 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
R> require(roll)
R> x = matrix(rnorm(100),100,1)
R> y = matrix(rnorm(100),100,1)
R> str(roll_lm(x,y,10))
List of 2
 $ coefficients: num [1:100, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "x1"
 $ r.squared   : num [1:100, 1] NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr "R-squared"
R>
```

I suggest you rebuild reinstall package [roll](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/roll/index.html).

Sometimes this happens when one component (Rcpp, RcppParallel, ...) gets updated.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just did it. Same problem.

Comment: Reinstall Rcpp. Reinstall RcppParallel. Reinstall roll.  Mine are all current, and things work. Things also work at CRAN:  https://cloud.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_roll.html -- so the ball remains in your corner.

Comment: Did it. I have the last version of each package. Still the same problem. Weird. I've noticed that roll_sd in the same package works.

Comment: Did you do binary or source installations? Do you have multiple library locations on your machine, having an older version shadow a new version?  I can't help you any more.  If it all fails, buy a new computer ;-)